# rosrun string parameter syntax

Tags: ros, rosrun, parameter-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to read an integer parameter as string however ros::param::get() does not read it.

```
std::string my_param;
if (ros::param::get("~x", my_param)) {
   ROS_INFO("value=%s", my_param.c_str());
}


rosrun planning planner _x:=12
rosrun planning planner _x:="12"
```

It cannot read parameters either way.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49406/rosrun-string-parameter-syntax/) by [Okan Aşık](https://answers.ros.org/users/3230/okan-a%C5%9F%C4%B1k/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2012-11-29

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Miquel Massot](https://answers.ros.org/users/2515/miquel-massot/) on 2012-11-29**:
Private parameters have to be read this way: http://www.ros.org/wiki/roscpp/Overview/Parameter%20Server#Accessing_Private_Parameters

**Comment by [Okan Aşık](https://answers.ros.org/users/3230/okan-a%C5%9F%C4%B1k/) on 2012-11-30**:
my code reads private parameters same as tutorial, but i want to read the parameter as string. isn't that possible when I write numbers.

**Comment by [Miquel Massot](https://answers.ros.org/users/2515/miquel-massot/) on 2012-12-18**:
have you tried itoa() ? http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/itoa/

**Comment by [Okan Aşık](https://answers.ros.org/users/3230/okan-a%C5%9F%C4%B1k/) on 2012-12-19**:
I solved my problem, but I just want to speculate that there might be a bug or a better explanation for such an unexpected case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I hit on this too: programs must know in advance the type of the parameter they are fetching, otherwise they may end up getting nothing from the server.
And there is no way to check the parameter type.

---

Originally posted by [Claudio](https://answers.ros.org/users/3152/claudio/) with karma: 859 on 2013-02-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0